# How can i add JFoenix to JavaFX 15?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, jfoenix

I am new to this JavaFX and I needed to add JFoenix jar file to my JavaFX project but i didn't find suitable version of JFoenix for JavaFX 15. Is there any way to add JFoenix 9 to JavaFX 15? or alternative for JFoenix?

I am using the following versions of libraries and IDE:

Eclipse 2020-12

JDK 15

JavaFX 15

JRE 1.8.0_281

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: What do you want to do with that JRE 1.8.0... if you already have JDK 15?

Comment: Maybe downgrade your JDK? I'm using JFoenix with JavaFX 15 but with OpenJDK 11. Works fine for me.